# No Overload For 'void' Matches Delegate 'ThreadStart'

Tags: c#

I want to run function with `void` as return type in new thread, but it always shows this error:

> No overload for 'myVoid' matches delegate 'ThreadStart'

and my code :

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myVoid)); // <-- Error Shows Here 
t.Start("Test","Test2");

// And The Void :
void myVoid(string text, string text2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text + text2);
}
```

How I fix it? What is wrong?

Comment: Your method needs to be parameter-less.  This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360555/how-to-pass-parameters-to-threadstart-method-in-thread

Comment: Signature of ThreadStart `public delegate void ThreadStart()` says that it expects a parameterless method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Threads -ThreadStart Delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782210/c-sharp-threads-threadstart-delegate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ThreadStart` delegate expects a delegate that takes no parameters. If you would like to use `myVoid` in a thread, you need to provide a way to make a match between `myVoid` and a no-argument delegate.

One way of doing it is by providing a *lambda*, like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => myVoid("Test", "Test2")));
t.Start();
```

Comment: Can be further simplified to: `Thread t = new Thread(() => myVoid("Test", "Test2"));`

Comment: Thankyou Very Much ! It Works

Answer (score 1):

The [ThreadStart delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) you are using does not define any arguments.

This means your method `myVoid` which has 2 string arguments does not match the delegate.